# How to check if Now time lies between a given time in AutoIt

Tags: time, autoit

I am trying to check if `Now` time is between, let's say, 13:00 and 17:00. I don't think the `_Datediff` function (using `_dateadd()` and `_NowTimeCalc()`) will work.

Is there some library function in [AutoIt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AutoIt) that I am missing? Or do I have to write a manual function comparing `@Hour` and `@min`?

I am doing something like this:

```
Func CheckTime($sStart, $sEnd)
    $s = StringSplit($sStart, ":")
    $e = StringSplit($sEnd, ":")
    $s[1] = Int($s[1])
    $s[2] = Int($s[2])
    $e[1] = Int($e[1])
    $e[2] = Int($e[2])
    $result = False

    If $s[0] <= 0 And $e <= 0 Then
        ConsoleWrite("Wrong Time Format")
        Exit
    EndIf

    If $s[1] <= @HOUR And $e[1] >= @HOUR Then
        If @HOUR >= $s[1] And @MIN > $s[2] Then
            If @HOUR <= $e[1] And @MIN < $e[2] Then
                $result = True
            EndIf
        EndIf
    EndIf
    Return $result
EndFunc  ; ==>CheckTime
```

For now works fine when start time < end time, but what I am looking for is some good method instead of manual checks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using standard user defined functions (UDFs), you can try using something like this:

```
#region    ;************ Includes ************
#include <Array.au3>
#include <Date.au3>
#endregion    ;************ Includes ************


ConsoleWrite(_timeBetween(@HOUR & ':' & @MIN, '10:05', '12:09'))

Func _timeBetween($cTime, $sTime, $eTime)
    If Not _DateIsValid('2000/01/01 ' & $cTime) Then Return -1
    If Not _DateIsValid('2000/01/01 ' & $sTime) Then Return -2
    If Not _DateIsValid('2000/01/01 ' & $eTime) Then Return -3

    ;~  ConsoleWrite(_DateDiff('s', '2000/01/01 ' & $cTime & ':00', '2000/01/01 ' & $sTime & ':00') & @CRLF)
    ;~  ConsoleWrite(_DateDiff('s', '2000/01/01 ' & $cTime & ':00', '2000/01/01 ' & $eTime & ':00') & @CRLF)

    If _DateDiff('s', '2000/01/01 ' & $cTime & ':00', '2000/01/01 ' & $sTime & ':00') < 0 And _
       _DateDiff('s', '2000/01/01 ' & $cTime & ':00', '2000/01/01 ' & $eTime & ':00') > 0 Then

        Return 1
    Else
        Return 0
    EndIf

EndFunc  ; ==>_timeBetween
```

Answer (score 1):

A simpler version that works for me - just using string compare in hh:mm format

```
#include <Date.au3>

Func _timeBetween( $sTime, $eTime)
    Return (_NowTime(4) < $eTime) And (_NowTime(4) > $eTime)
EndFunc  ; ==>_timeBetween


MsgBox(0, "daytime","is day = " & _timeBetween("08:00"."23:00") )
```

Comment: Nice, but this wouldn't work for crossing the midnight, e.g. for a time between 22:00 and 02:00